# Where should I connect a C wire on my Goodman PGB030075-1 furnace?

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

Is this where I can piggyback for c wire on Vine thermostat?

[image]

Thanks

[image: I]

Comment: Can you measure 24V from R to C on your control board?

Comment: I don't know will have to check, now I read on another thread "If there's an empty terminal on the transformer, connect there."  And as per picture about I have an empty middle terminal

Answer (score 1):

### Right part, wrong wire

While the terminal you have circled does attach to the transformer, it attaches to the *primary* side of the transformer (i.e. the AC mains side).  You need the *secondary* side common, which on [your system](http://igate.northernplumbing.com/manuals/goodman/pgb.pdf) is the blue wire coming off the transformer (if there are multiple blue wires leading to that terminal, you can tap any of them).

Comment: Shouldn't need to tap it there the board appears to have a C terminal at the bottom next to the G which should be connected to the transformer COM via board trace.

Comment: @DanD. -- can you point out where that C terminal is? I don't see one in the photo posted, nor is there one in the wiring diagrams in the manual I found...

Comment: It is on page 13 of the manual you linked to on the relay board you have to zoom in to read the terminal labels.

Comment: @DanD. -- that may be a different model of control than what the OP has...

Comment: No blue wire, please see the new picture

Comment: I found the c terminal and wired thernostat to it, didn't work, tested no power

Comment: Where did you find the C terminal at? Can you edit a photo of that into your question?

Comment: The top picture, the bottom right is where I found the c terminal

Comment: I may of hook the blue wire to the thermostat and black wire to c terminal wire.  Hot week here so will try later when the temperature comes down